# Python Tkinter - processing data entered by a user

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create a program in Python with Tkinter GUI, and I want it to take string inputs from a user, then I want to do some operations on these strings - in this case, I want to mix parts of two words and get a new word. How can I handle this data entered by a user and use it to receive the result? Below is my code. I couldn't find the answer to this problem and nothing I tried works.

```
from Tkinter import *    
class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()      
    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Mix words")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        menu = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menu)
        entryLbl1 = Label(self, text="Write the first word: ")
        entryLbl1.pack()
        self.entrytext1 = StringVar()
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.entrytext1).pack()
        self.buttontext1 = StringVar()
        self.buttontext1.set("OK")
        Button(self, textvariable=self.buttontext1, command=self.clicked1).pack()
        self.label1 = Label(self, text="")
        self.label1.pack()
        global user_entry1 
        user_entry1 = self.entrytext1.get()
        entryLbl2 = Label(self, text="Write the second word: ")
        entryLbl2.pack()
        self.entrytext2 = StringVar()
        Entry(self, textvariable=self.entrytext2).pack()
        self.buttontext2 = StringVar()
        self.buttontext2.set("OK")
        Button(self, textvariable=self.buttontext2, command=self.clicked2).pack()
        self.label2 = Label(self, text="")
        self.label2.pack()
        global user_entry2
        user_entry2 = self.entrytext2.get()
        entryLbl3 = Label(self, text="Result: ")
        entryLbl3.pack()
        self.buttontext3 = StringVar()
        self.buttontext3.set("Result")
        Button(self, textvariable=self.buttontext1, command=self.clicked3).pack()
        self.label3 = Label(self, text="")
        self.label3.pack()        
    def clicked1(self):
        input = self.entrytext1.get()
        self.label1.configure(text=input)
    def clicked2(self):
        input = self.entrytext2.get()
        self.label2.configure(text=input)
    def clicked3(self):
        self.user_entry1 = user_entry1
        self.user_entry2 = user_entry2
        first2a = user_entry1[0:2]
        rest_a = user_entry1[2:]
        first2b = user_entry2[0:2]
        rest_b = user_entry2[2:]
        input = first2b + rest_a + " " + first2a + rest_b
        self.label3.configure(text=input)
root = Tk()
root.iconbitmap("py.ico")
root.geometry("600x300")
app = Window(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `I couldn't find the answer to this problem and nothing I tried works.` Can you provide some examples of what you have tried?  What controls are you looking to combine? Is your question about how to access the control value or how to combine the strings? The more information you can provide about your question will make it more likely that someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Entry()` objects.

The following will show two `Entry` widgets and a `Button`.
When the button is pressed, the contents of both of the `Entry` objects will be printed to the console:

```
import sys


# Determine if you're running Python 3
is_py_3 = sys.version[0] == '3'


# Import Tkinter for the correct version of Python
if is_py_3:
    from tkinter import Button, Entry, Tk
else:
    from Tkinter import Button, Entry, Tk

class GUI:

    def __init__(self):

        # Set up the "Root" or "Parent" of the window.
        self.root = Tk()

        # Set up two "Entry" widgets.
        self.entry1 = Entry(self.root)
        self.entry1.insert(0, "Enter something here.")

        self.entry2 = Entry(self.root)
        self.entry2.insert(0, "and here...")

        # Set up a button to handle the event.
        self.button = Button(self.root, text="CLICK ME", command=self.onClicked)

        self.entry1.pack()
        self.entry2.pack()
        self.button.pack()

    def onClicked(self):
        # Print the contents of the entry widgets.
        s1 = self.entry1.get()
        s2 = self.entry2.get()

        print(s1, s2)


app = GUI()
app.root.mainloop()
```